# .DTX won't load corresponding .STY

Tags: dtx

I'm preparing a documented source for a package file and I basically use the skeleton from the ltxdoc manual verbatim. For some reason, when I compile the .dtx to generate the documentation, it just won't load the style file though. No error that it can't find it, either.

```
% \iffalse meta-comment
%
%
% Copyright (C) 2014 by Richard Zach <rzach@ucalgary.ca>
% ------------------------------------------------------
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3
% of this license or (at your option) any later version.
% The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3 or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
% version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status `maintained'.
% 
% The Current Maintainer of this work is Richard Zach.
%
% This work consists of the files bpextra.dtx, bpextra.ins, bpextra.sty
%
% \fi
%
% \iffalse
%<*driver>
\ProvidesFile{bpextra.sty}
%</driver>
%<package>\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
%<package>\ProvidesPackage{bpextra}
%<package>   [2014/04/26 0.1 Extra commands for bussproofs.sty]
%<*driver>
\documentclass{ltxdoc}

\usepackage{bpextra}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\renewcommand{\fCenter}{\ensuremath{\,{\to}\,}}

\EnableCrossrefs         
\CodelineIndex
\RecordChanges
\begin{document}
  \DocInput{bpextra.dtx}
  \PrintChanges
  \PrintIndex
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
%
% \CheckSum{0}
%
% \CharacterTable
%  {Upper-case    \A\B\C\D\E\F\G\H\I\J\K\L\M\N\O\P\Q\R\S\T\U\V\W\X\Y\Z
%   Lower-case    \a\b\c\d\e\f\g\h\i\j\k\l\m\n\o\p\q\r\s\t\u\v\w\x\y\z
%   Digits        \0\1\2\3\4\5\6\7\8\9
%   Exclamation   \!     Double quote  \"     Hash (number) \#
%   Dollar        \$     Percent       \%     Ampersand     \&
%   Acute accent  \'     Left paren    \(     Right paren   \)
%   Asterisk      \*     Plus          \+     Comma         \,
%   Minus         \-     Point         \.     Solidus       \/
%   Colon         \:     Semicolon     \;     Less than     \<
%   Equals        \=     Greater than  \>     Question mark \?
%   Commercial at \@     Left bracket  \[     Backslash     \\
%   Right bracket \]     Circumflex    \^     Underscore    \_
%   Grave accent  \`     Left brace    \{     Vertical bar  \|
%   Right brace   \}     Tilde         \~}
%
%
% \changes{v0.1}{2014/04/26}{Initial version with deduce, linelabel 
%    functionality}
%
% \GetFileInfo{bpextra.sty}
%
% \DoNotIndex{\newcommand,\newenvironment}
%
%
% \title{The \textsf{bpextra} package\thanks{This document
%   corresponds to \textsf{bpextra}~\fileversion, dated \filedate.}}
% \author{\href{http://ucalgary.ca/rzach/}{Richard Zach}}
% \date{}
%
% \maketitle
%
% \section{Introduction}
%
```

The full file is here: https://github.com/OpenLogicProject/bpextra

Comment: Note that for packages the usual trick is to have the driver load the package: that way you only need the `\ProvidesPackage` line for `\GetFileInto` to work. I'd also argue that the character table is nowadays redundant (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159902/character-table-on-style-files).

Answer (score 4):

You should have

```
%<*driver>
\ProvidesFile{bpextra.dtx}
%</driver>
```

and not

```
%<*driver>
\ProvidesFile{bpextra.sty}
%</driver>
```